# Set multiple items with setItems

Tags: sencha-touch-2

As title, is it possible to use setItems to set the items to show on a panel?

If say the panel has an id : 'panel'

So the code becomes

```
setPanelItems: function (){
    var number = [],
    panel = Ext.getCmp('panel');

    number = this.num.numVal;

    for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
        if (panel){
            switch(number[i]){
                case 1:
                panel.setItems(this.itemOne);
                break;

                case 2:
                panel.setItems(this.itemTwo);
                break;

                case 3:
                panel.setItems(this.itemThree);
                break;

                case 4:
                panel.setItems(this.itemFour);
                break;

                default:
                console.log('No item matched');
            }
        }
    }
},

num: {numVal: [1,2]},

itemOne: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        //item blocks in here
    }
],

itemTwo: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        //item blocks in here
    }
],

itemThree: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        //item blocks in here
    }
],

itemFour: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        //item blocks in here
    }
],
```

I managed to dynamically add the item based on the number and show it on the panel accordingly. But here comes the problem, when i tried to add 2 or more items into the panel, only 1 item will be shown. For example if i want to show item 1 and item 4 together in the panel, only item 4 will be shown, and i suspect that item 1 was overwritten by item 4 in the switch block. I tried multiple solutions, like below

```
panel.setItems(this.itemOne, this.itemTwo);

panel.setItems([this.itemOne, this.itemTwo]);

panel.setItems({this.itemOne, this.itemTwo});
```

But neither works.

I want to know if my method in adding items to the panel was wrong, or was there anything that i missed?

EDIT:

Added source code to my post

```
Ext.define('view.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'survey',
    id: 'survey',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.*',
        'Ext.field.*',
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.Toolbar',
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],

    config: {

        centered: true,
        modal: true,
        height: '95%',
        width: '95%',
        margin: '1%',
        hideOnMaskTap: true,

        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true,
        },

        defaults: {
            required: true
        },

        items: [

            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                action: 'formTitle',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Simple survey'
            },

            {
               xtype: 'panel',
               id: 'panel',
               layout: {type: 'vbox'}
               //items: []
            }
        ]
    },

    initialize: function () {
        var me = this;
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.setPanel();
    },

    setPanel: function () {
        var num = [],
            panel = Ext.getCmp("panel");

        num = this.number.numArr;

        for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            if (panel){
                    switch (num[i]){
                    case 1:
                        //To be done
                        panel.setItems(this.itemOne);
                        console.log('Number 1');
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        //to be done
                        panel.setItems(this.itemTwo);
                        console.log('Number 2');
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        //to be done
                        panel.setItems(this.itemThree);
                        console.log('Number 3');
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        //to be done
                        panel.setItems(this.itemFour);
                        console.log('Number 4');
                        break;

                    default:
                        console.log('No number matching');
                }
            }
        }
    },

    number: {
        numArr : [1, 3]
    },

    itemOne: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'How is the overall rating?',
            defaults: { xtype: 'radiofield' },
            items: [
                { name : 'rating', label: 'Excellent', value: 'excellent' },
                { name : 'rating', label: 'Good', value: 'good' },
            ]
        },
    ],

    itemTwo: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'How is the overall quality?',
            defaults: { xtype: 'radiofield' },
            items: [
                { name : 'quality', label: 'Excellent', value: 'excellent' },
                { name : 'quality', label: 'Good', value: 'good' },
            ]
        },
    ],

    itemThree: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Do you like it?',
            defaults: { xtype: 'radiofield' },
            items: [
                { name : 'acceptance', label: 'Love it', value: 'loveIt' },
                { name : 'acceptance', label: 'Like it', value: 'likeIt' },
            ]
        },
    ],

    itemFour: [
        {
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            required: false,
            maxRows: 3,
            name: 'anyComments',
            label: 'Anything you wanna add?',
            labelAlign: 'top'
        },
    ]

});
```

I want so that if based on any condition, any of the items can be shown on the panel without problem.

Comment: What is the layout for items container, does it support displaying multiple items at one time?

Comment: I didn't set.. but even when i added layout:{type:'vbox'} into the config, and it popped out an error >> Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#factoryItem] Invalid config, must be a valid config object

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to set multiple items with `setItems`

`panel.setItems([this.itemOne, this.itemTwo]);`

If your panel just shows one item, be sure that its (the parent container) `layout` config is not `'card'`, you should use `vbox`, `hbox` or just `default` for your `layout` config, for example if you want to arrange your items vertically, one below another, you should add `layout: 'vbox'`

Comment: I added layout:{type:'vbox'} to the config and i follow the way you put above, but it popped out an error >> Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#factoryItem] Invalid config, must be a valid config object

Comment: what if you change from `panel` to `container`?

Comment: Not working too.. when i tried panel.setItems([this.itemOne, this.itemTwo]), it popped out that same error.. and when i tried to set panel.setItems(this.itemOne) and panel.setItems(this.itemFour), only itemFour will be shown on the panel..